# Using bid and ask prices with VectorBT library

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, back-testing, vectorbt

I am creating a backtest using vectorbt library. This is my function for all the portfolio metrics:

```
pf = vbt.Portfolio.from_signals(
    signal_data['close'],
    entries,
    exits,
    init_cash=10_000_000,
    freq='D'
)
```

Now, instead of using the close price I want to switch to bid and ask prices for my trades.

Is there a convenient way to do this?